# What's the algorithm wikipedia uses for their version comparison feature

Tags: java, algorithm, comparison, versioning, revision

I am currently implementing some sort of text-version (revision) comparison visualizations and am trying to find some information about how wikipedia achieves their "View History"-feature in which they allow to compare the current revision with an older one.

You can find one example (About stackoverflow!) here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stack_Overflow&diff=512241244&oldid=458578615

I have implemented several ideas so far and also tried to reproduce the way wikipedia is doing it. For this I've implemented the Levenshtein-distance algorithm ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance ).

Lets assume I have two lists. I am iterating over the first list and check for the index-position of the first list on the second if the string found there is more than 50% equal. If it is, I'll just print both Strings side by side in my comparison view and continue with the next item of the first list. If it is not, I check the next item in the second list until I find it or leave the field for the second list blank if it cannot be found. (Although I would basically prefer that a sentence from the second list also always appears on the comparison view instead of leaving it out, just e.g. with a blank field for the first list field)

This method has some weaknesses. At first, if some sentence got deleted I would need to check the positions around the index for not simply "forgetting" it. But still I need to take care that text positions don't get inverted if I do so.

Has anyone of you tried to achieve something similar with java? If there are some code examples how others or you achieved it, I would gladly take a look to learn from it.

And of course, if you know anything about the algorithm wikipedia (and general wikis I assume?) uses for their revision comparison I'd be glad to hear it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia explains how the wiki difference engine works - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Diff

You can follow the links at the bottom of the page to learn more, but [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aWiki_diff) lists the template used.

Answer (score 3):

Another implementation besides Wikipedia's version control is `diff` on Unix flavor systems. GNU actually makes the source code available for [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) which may enable you to look at their algorithms here:

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/diffutils/

Comment: there is also svn diff. which is nice. there is a beyond compare software which is cool as well.